# Setting up a server to host multiple domains using django, virtualenv, gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, virtualenv

I am setting up a new server machine, which will host multiple django websites.

I must point out that I own (developed and are in absolute control of) all websites that will be run on the server.

I am pretty certain that *ALL* of the websites will be using the same version of:

- django
- gunicorn
- nginx
- postgreSQL and psycopg2 (all though some websites will be using geospatial and other extensions)

The only thing that I know will differ between the django applications are:

- python modules used (which may have implications for version of python required)

I can understand using virtualenv to manage instances of where a project has specific python modules (or even python version requirements), but it seems  pretty wasteful to me (in terms of resources), to have each project (via virtualenv), to have separate installations of django, nginx, gunicorn ... etc.

My question then is this:

**Is it 'acceptable' (or considered best practice in scenarios such as that outlined above) to *globally* install django, gunicorn, nginx, postgreSQL and psycopg2 and simply use virtualenv to manage only the parts (e.g. python modules/versions) that differ between projects?.**

Note: In this scenario there'll be one nginx server handling multiple domains.

Last but not the least, is it possible to use virtualenv to manage different postgreSQL extensions in different projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It would probably work, but it would be a bad idea.

Firstly, it's not clear what kind of "resources" you think would be wasted. The only relevant thing is disk space, and we're talking about a few megabytes only; not even worth thinking about.

Secondly, you'd now make it impossible to upgrade any of them individually; for anything beyond a trivial upgrade, you'd need to test and release them all together, rather than just doing what you need and deploying that one on its own.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input. But nginx binds to a port, so clearly, it doesn't make sense to install nginx in each virtualenv - since only one instance of nginx can bind to port 80 (or 443) - am I missiing something here?

Comment: You can't install nginx in a virtualenv. Virtualenvs are for Python libraries. nginx is installed at system level and proxies to the sites, each of which is running inside a virtualenv. Similarly, Postgres is installed and runs globally but psycopg is installed for each env.

Comment: Can you just confirm if my understanding is correct: [postgresql, nginx, virtualenv] <- installed globally, [django, gunicorn, python version/models etc, pysopg2] <- installed inside a virtualenv.   Note specifically, that *gunicorn* is in a virtualenv. I'm struggling to see how this would work (each application having its own gunicorn instance), and yet all binding to the same port (Apache2 old hand here ...)

Comment: Yes. But the gunicorn instances wouldn't bind to the same port. They'd bind to individual ports, or even better sockets, and nginx would proxy from port 80 to the individual ones.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider it advisable.

By doing that, you are creating a dependency between the projects which means you'll never be able to upgrade one without all the others. Which would be a massive PITA.

Eventually it would get to a point where you could never upgrade because Project A's dependency foo doesnt work with django 1.N but Project B's dependency bar requires at least 1.N - At which point you fall back to the cleaner solution anyway, separate environments.

That applies to the django side of things at least, it may work slightly better with Postgres and Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use docker virtualization so that every project has it's own scope and doesn't interfere with other projects.

I'm currently having such configuration on multiple servers and I'm really happy with it because I'm really flexible and what is really important - I'm secure, because if any of projects has critical bugs in it, other projects are still safe.